# Search list of string elements that match another list of string elements

Tags: python

I have a list with strings called `names`, I need to search each element in the `names` list with each element from the `pattern` list. Found several guides that can loop through for a individual string but not for a list of strings

```
a = [x for x in names if 'st' in x]
```

Thank you in advance!

```
names = ['chris', 'christopher', 'bob', 'bobby', 'kristina']
pattern = ['st', 'bb']
```

Desired output:

```
a = ['christopher', 'bobby', 'kristina]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
a = [x for x in names if any(pat in x for pat in pattern)]
```

`any()` is a short-circuiting function, so the first time it comes across a pattern that matches, it returns True.  Since I am using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension, no patterns after the first pattern that matches are even checked.  That means that this is just about the fastest possible way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
[name for name in names if any([p in name for p in pattern])]
```

The code is self explanatory, just read it out loud; we're creating a list of all names that have one of the patterns in them.

Using two loops:

```
for name in names:
    for pattern in patterns:
        if pattern in name:
            # append to result
```